# AWS codepipeline using Lambda function

Tags: continuous-integration, pipeline

1. Can we use AWS lambda function for various stages like deploy, build etc., in AWS codepipeline?  AWS lambda function will have endpoint and will be responsible to provide Success/Failure result for the job.
2. I didn't see an option to provide URL for lambda where user can can give during pipeline setup for Lambda function provider.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You can use an AWS CodePipeline to use AWS CodeDeploy to Lambda.  There is even an official AWS tutorial you can follow [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/build-pipeline.html).

Comment: May be my question was not clear. In codepipeline custom action I see Job would be script and this script can be changed to use in any stages by changing the category in config.Instead of script can we provide Lambda function ? I see only during Invoke after deploy stage but not during Build/deploy/test.